# Rails, using a belongs_to and has_one association to the same class

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

Here's a picture I made which visually describes the relationship I'm seeking: [image]

In the picture I say `Interaction`, but more specifically these interactions are in-game Kills. A kill, as we all know, has the killer, and the victim. In this case our killer will be called `player`, and our victim will be called `victim`.

Given this picture, here are some example queries I'd like to perform:

```
Player.find(1).Interactions
> [<#Interaction id: 1>, <#Interaction id: 2>, <#Interaction id: 3>]

Interactions.where(player: Player.find(1))
> [<#Interaction id: 1>, <#Interaction id: 2>, <#Interaction id: 3>]

Interactions.where(victim: Player.find(1))
> [<#Interaction id: 4>]

Player.find(1).Interactions.where(victim: Player.find(2))
> [<#Interaction id: 2>]

Player.find(1).Interactions.count()
> 3

# Player.find(1).Interactions should (ideally) return Interactions where <#Player id: 1> is the player (not victim)

Interactions.all.count()
> 4

Player.all.count()
> 4

Player.find(2).Interactions
> []

Player.find(3).Interactions
> [ <#Interaction id: 4> ]

Player.find(4).Interactions
> []
```

I've tried a lot of different associations (I've been digging through google and Stack Overflow results for hours)

This is how I think my `Interaction` model should look:

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_one :victim, :class_name => 'Player'
end
```

And my `Player` model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_man :kills
end
```

And finally, how I think the migration should look:

```
class CreatePlayerAndInteraction < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :steam_id
    end

    create_table :interactions do |t|
      t.string :weapon
      t.belongs_to :player, index: true
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey!! It's that simple, thank you. If you make an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interactions` table just needs a `victim_id` column and then change the `has_one` to `belongs_to :victim, class_name: Player`.

This will work since an `Interaction` is basically a join table of `Player` to `Player`.

`has_one` implies that the victim (`Player` in this case) would have a `interaction_id` which is incorrect.

Instead an `Interaction` belongs to the killer and the victim.

Setup as:

```
class Player
  has_many :kills, class_name: Interaction, foreign_key: :player_id inverse_of: :killer
  has_many :deaths, class_name: Interaction, foreign_key: :victim_id, inverse_of: :victim 
end

class Interaction
  belongs_to :killer, class_name: Player, foreign_key: :player_id, inverse_of: :kills
  belongs_to :victim, class_name: Player, foreign_key: :victim_id, inverse_of :deaths
end
```

Answer (score 0):

engineersmnky gave me a great answer which helped me solve the problem, but it has a little more fluff. Here's the exact solution I used to solve my problem:

```
# ./models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interactions
end

# ./models/interaction.rb
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :victim, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'victim_id'
end

# ./db/migrate/migrate/create_players.rb
class CreatePlayersAndInteractions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :interactions do |t|
      t.integer :victim_id
      t.belongs_to :player, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Change `Interaction` to `Kill` or this makes no sense and also my "fluff"is functionality right now based on this a `Player` kind of has kills but does not have deathes

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for pointing that out! I fixed it. The reason I say there's some fluff, is because a death isn't necessarily the inverse of a kill. Players can die in other ways. I wanted to make sure there was a clear, barebones answer to the question. Thank you for the help!